# Help getting started with formal notation

Tags: logic, reference-request, predicate-logic

I have this question -

Rewrite the statement “there are integers m and n such that 1/m + 1/n is an integer” using the formal notation containing quantifier and universe notations so that it is in the form ∀n ∈ Z (n2 ≥ n)

Can I get some explanations on what its asking me to do/some resource suggestions etc... without giving me the answer. I am completely new to this and honestly don't understand the question at all so some info to start me off would be nice. Like what do I need to google/learn/research to learn how to answer these kinds of questions. Thank you.

Comment: Try to rewrite it semi-formally: there is an integer $m$, there is an integer $n$ such that : for every $k$ (if $k= \dfrac 1 m + \dfrac 1 n$, then $k$ is an integer)".

Comment: Try googling [Predicate Logic](http://www.mafy.lut.fi/study/LogicAndDiscreteMethods/Lectures/Lecture2.pdf).

Comment: Where do you get that task from? It looks like it's homework, in which case you ought to have a textbook or other course material that introduces you to the notation you're supposed to use.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is homework, the resources i was given from the course really didn't help me understand it so I needed to look elsewhere.